# Como selecionar um valor de um <option> pelo AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Bem, faço uma interação para obter as opções, e quero que seja selecionado a primeira opção

```
             <select class="form-control" 
                      name="accounts"
                      ng-model="vm.deposit.account"
                      ng-options="account.account as account.agency for account in vm.accounts"
                      required>
              </select>
```

Minha intenção é tentar da tipo 'Selected'. Já tentei usar ng-select, porém foi sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro remova o [`select as` da expressão `ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select class="form-control" name="accounts" 
    ng-model="vm.deposit.account" 
    ng-options="account.agency for account in vm.accounts" 
    required=""></select>
```

Depois, em seu `controller` *set* o modelo (no caso, `vm.deposit.account`) com valor que deve vir como selecionado por padrão:

```
$scope.vm.deposit = {
    account: $scope.vm.accounts[0] // o primeiro valor do array
};
```

Exemplo completo:

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.vm = {
        accounts: [{
          agency: 'Agency 1',
          account: 'a1'
        }, {
          agency: 'Agency 2',
          account: 'a2'
        }, {
          agency: 'Agency 3',
          account: 'a3'
        }]
      };

      $scope.vm.deposit = {
        account: $scope.vm.accounts[1] // o segundo valor do array
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <select class="form-control" name="accounts" ng-model="vm.deposit.account" ng-options="account.agency for account in vm.accounts" required=""></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo online completo.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/ks7oL5a3/3/)